# A website that returns a JSON look-a-like but I am unable to parse it in Python

Tags: python, asp.net, json

I am trying to read the JSON file off the website "`https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/getJSON.aspx?sd=20230101&ed=20230331&sb=0`".

When I open the site using browser, copy and paste the text shown in site to a JSON viewer, it does reveal a valid strcuture.

Any idea why it is not working with usual method `requests.get('url').json()`?

I want a working code that can read the site and store the JSON into a variable using Python.

Comment: why is `'url'` a string in `requests.get('url').json()`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I tried `requests.get('https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/getJSON.aspx?sd=20230101&ed=20230331&sb=0').json()`

Answer (score 1):

#### The website is returning a program that *then* requests the JSON

```
response = requests.get("https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/getJSON.aspx?sd=20230101&ed=20230331&sb=0")
```

The response is this:

```html
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
Challenge=485021;
ChallengeId=1251691391;
GenericErrorMessageCookies="Cookies must be enabled in order to view this page.";
</script>
<script>
function test(var1)
{
        var var_str=""+Challenge;
        var var_arr=var_str.split("");
        var LastDig=var_arr.reverse()[0];
        var minDig=var_arr.sort()[0];
        var subvar1 = (2 * (var_arr[2]))+(var_arr[1]*1);
        var subvar2 = (2 * var_arr[2])+var_arr[1];
        var my_pow=Math.pow(((var_arr[0]*1)+2),var_arr[1]);
        var x=(var1*3+subvar1)*1;
        var y=Math.cos(Math.PI*subvar2);
        var answer=x*y;
        answer-=my_pow*1;
        answer+=(minDig*1)-(LastDig*1);
        answer=answer+subvar2;
        return answer;
}
</script>
<script>
client = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
        var client=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
                client = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        };
}
if (!((!!client)&&(!!Math.pow)&&(!!Math.cos)&&(!![].sort)&&(!![].reverse)))
{
        document.write("Not all needed JavaScript methods are supported.<BR>");

}
else
{
        client.onreadystatechange  = function()
        {
                if(client.readyState  == 4)
                {
                        var MyCookie=client.getResponseHeader("X-AA-Cookie-Value");
                        {
                                document.write(client.responseText);
                                return;
                        }

                        var cookieName = MyCookie.split('=')[0];
                        if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName)==-1)
                        {
                                document.write(GenericErrorMessageCookies);
                                return;
                        }
                        window.location.reload(true);
                }
        };
        y=test(Challenge);
        client.open("POST",window.location,true);
        client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-ID', ChallengeId);
        client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-Result',y);
        client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge',Challenge);
        client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' , 'text/plain');
        client.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>JavaScript must be enabled in order to view this page.</noscript>
</body>
</HTML>
```

#### This is the key part sending the request:

```
        y=test(Challenge);
        client.open("POST",window.location,true);
        client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-ID', ChallengeId);
        client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-Result',y);
        client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge',Challenge);
        client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' , 'text/plain');
        client.send();
```

*That* request is what returns the JSON.

Comment: However If I open the url in a browser, the page is indeed a string with JSON format.

Comment: Is there a way to get the JSON path? Or is it possible to parse it in Python?

Comment: @jackytsz You must actually read the answer that Eureka provides. It explains why you see JSON when visiting that page, and explains why your request to that site is not returning the JSON you're expecting. If you have a specific question about ho that code works, by all means ask. But your comment makes it sound like you didn't make any attempt to actually comprehend the answer, and thus defeats the point of answering in the first place.

Comment: Apology that I was not very proficient in understanding the html codes, sorry to let you think I didn't read through his answer. My rough understanding was that it required me to open using a browser, and I was hoping there is a workaround in Python that I still can fetch the JSON out of it.